# GWT. Get initial POST parameters

Tags: java, gwt

My app started by another app, and at initiating it must get POST parameters. I read that i can get GET parameters using `Window.Location.getParameter`  . But I need to get POST parameter from request. How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

"get" in `getParameter()` means "retrieve", it's the standard Java naming convention for getters; it has nothing to do with the HTTP request method.

Comment: so it mean that with method getParameter() i can also retrieve POST parameters?

Comment: No, because that method is only for URL parameters, you can't access POST parameters in GWT.